# Degree defined in Evans' PDE chapter 8 problem 5

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

This is a repost concerning the same problem asked in [Null Lagrangians and "Local Degree"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264845/null-lagrangians-and-local-degree).

The problem is Evans' PDE exercise 8.5

> Suppose $U$ is a bounded open subset on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $u: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be smooth. Fix $x_0 \notin \partial U$, and choose a $C^1$ function $\eta: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $supp(\eta) \subset B(x_0,r)$, where $r > 0$ is taken sufficiently small s.t. $B(x_0,r) \cap u(\partial U) = \emptyset$ and $\int_{B(x_0, r)} \eta =1$. Define the degree of $u$ relative to $x_0$ by
> $$\text{deg}(u,x_0) = \int_U \eta(u) \det(Du)dx.$$
> Show that  $\text{deg}(u,x_0)$ is an integer.

One observation (proved in Evans' exercise 8.4) is that $L(P,z,x) := \eta(z) \det(P)$ is a null lagrangian. So $\int_U \eta(u) \det(Du)dx$ depends only on $u|_{\partial(U)}$.

My questions:

1. Using the fact that $L$ is null lagrangian, for each $u$, I think we could always define another function $w$ such that $w \equiv u$ on $\partial U$, and $w^{-1}(B(x_0,r)) \cap U = \emptyset$. In this case the degree should be identically $0$. I believe this is wrong, but I don't see which part is problematic;
2. How should I approach this problem? I think we need to do change of variable somewhere because the form of the integral defining the degree; but here the sign of the $\det$ is changing.

Could you give some hint or suggestion? I appreciate it very much!

Comment: Can you use Sard theorem?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, by Sard theorem we have $\{x: \det Du(x) = 0\}$ has zero measure. And following (i), and (ii) in the comment in the post I mentioned at the beginning, we could make $supp(\eta)$ contains no critical point of $u$. Could you say more about it? I am not familiar with covering map mentioned in (ii).

Comment: This seems to be the "degree" of a map as in differential geometry. There is a formula for the degree in terms of a sum of signs of the Jacobian matrix at chosen points, which is an integer. You can find it in Lee's book on Smooth Manifolds.

Comment: Why is the approach in (1) wrong though?